# IntelliJ 12.1 Community: Structural Search ... Not there?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, structural-search

I just cannot find this option anywhere (Using IntelliJ 12.1.4 Community). Despite furious googling, I can't find anything about this feature being removed, or being Ultimate only, or anything.

Edit > Find is supposed to have a "Search Structurally" option. It's not there.

Inspections is also meant to have an option to make a structural template (See http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-own-inspections.html)

"In the list of inspections, expand the General node and select the check box next to the Structural Search Inspection item. This enables the controls in the Options area, where you can configure a custom inspection."

That ain't there either. Any suggestions, anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html.

It's under "Supported only in Ultimate Edition".

Comment: Since IntelliJ IDEA 14 Structural Search and Replace is included in the Community edition.